# Best puzzles of 2020 Q4 (October - December)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the fourth quarter ( October / November / December) 2020?

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

> **Algorithmically selected "best of"**:
>
> - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2020 Q4](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2020&month=10#query-results)
> - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2020 Q4](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2020&month=10#query-results)
>
> **Best by votes/views:**
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2020 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2020/10/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2020 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2020/10/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2020 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2020/10/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

- <sub>Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>

  - <sub>Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>
- <sub>What's the point?</sub>
- <sub>To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
- <sub>To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
- <sub>To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

### [Another Straightforward 4-letters Crossword?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105216/) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719/athin)

Everyone knows what a crossword is, yes? I mean, you just solve the clues and put the answers in the grid, right?

**WRONG!** For me, this puzzle has been one of the highlights of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge so far. This crossword was so unsolvable it took 2 whole days before it fell - and once it did fall (to Deusovi) reading the solution was a real facepalm moment for anybody who usually prides themselves on being an 'outside the box' thinker!

A cunning twist on possibly the best known puzzle type across the globe - a twist I had not seen before, and did not spot this time. Well conceived, cleverly concealed - just very impressive altogether!

Answer (score 5):

### [Chain Puzzle: Tabletop Games #10 – Risky Finale](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105330/chain-puzzle-tabletop-games-10-risky-finale) by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)

How much more need I say? This puzzle was *amazing*, the perfect finish to the first Chain Puzzle series. It somehow managed to incorporate *every previous puzzle's answer* in an interesting way. Add in a smooth execution and presentation, and this wonder is most definitely worthy of nomination.

Answer (score 4):

### [Connect Wall - Grid Puzzles Edition!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104498) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)

I really, really enjoyed this puzzle. It included **16** different logic grid puzzles in a Connect Wall...peak PSE! It didn't get as much love as I felt it should have during the FTC, so hopefully this will bring it some more attention.

Answer (score 3):

### [Graylocke's Rotting Marble Box](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105993/71652) by [Graylocke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33242/graylocke)

This one is a giant contraption full of interesting mechanics. I appreciate the work involved to design one that looks very complicated at first glance but hides a nice property (and also to produce the graphic).